# C++ STL remove error

Tags: c++, string, stl

I'm having trouble understanding where I went wrong with my code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    string str = "";
    cin >> str;
    remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ' ');
    cout << str;
    cin.ignore();
}
```

The error says "'remove': function does not take 3 arguments (C2660)"

Comment: You were ending up calling [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2da4hk1d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) function instead.

Comment: +1 for providing a complete minimal example program. http://sscce.org

Comment: @Jon: Nice catch. That's why I prefer not to use `using namespace std` as it hides all manner of functions.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try adding

```
#include <algorithm>
```

"algorithm" is an STL header containing a lot of functions, including std::remove, which the OP is trying to call. The error he got was because there is another function that takes a single argument, called "remove", which deletes a file.

Comment: Gotta wait 10 minutes before I can!

Comment: @StilesCrisis I think you should explain what `<algorithm>` is, then you'll get also +1 from me :)

Comment: I know what <algorithm> is, I just forgot completely about it! But yes, that would be a good idea for other people.

Comment: @StilesCrisis Use comment of Jon to make your answer even better.

Comment: @Beginner: <algorithm> is an STL header containing a lot of functions, including std::remove, which the OP is trying to call. The error he got was because there is another function that takes a single argument, called "remove", which deletes a file.

Comment: @StilesCrisis I know it. That was merely to make the answer better. +1