# C++ Remove element from vector by value

Tags: c++, vector

I've looked around, and it seems to me that the consensus answer for this problem is this method;

```
template <typename T>
void removeByValue(vector<T> & vec, const T & val)
{
    vec.erase(std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), val), vec.end());
}
```

However, I get the error `error C2660: 'remove' : function does not take 3 arguments` when trying to compile it. Why is it giving me this error?

Comment: I am using visual studio 2013.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ STL remove error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394393/c-stl-remove-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::remove` is only available if you include header `<algorithm>`.

This is clearly stated by [the MSDN documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc854aef.aspx) as well as any C++ reference.

Comment: Thanks! Why don't any of the other answers mention this?

Comment: @Maurdekye: Because looking at the documentation for any built-in function to find out what header(s) are required is so basic, most C++ programmers never consider that students may not yet have learned it.

Comment: The error it threw for me wasn't that it was undefined, rather that it was defined, but took a different number of arguments. So it would be easy to mistake as a standard method.

Comment: @Maurdekye: Is it fixed now?

Comment: Yes, it is. But I can't mark your answer for another 7 minutes.

Comment: Apparently, if you include `<iostream>`, it's required to include `<cstdio>`, which of course brings in a lot of other potentially undesired things (`std::printf`, C's `std::remove`, etc.). §27.4.2/1: "The header `<iostream>` declares objects that associate objects with the standard C streams provided for by the functions declared in `<cstdio>` (27.9.2), and includes all the headers necessary to use these objects."

Comment: @remylabel: Well, it isn't required to include `<cstdio>`, using forward declarations instead is allowed.  But including other headers is allowed and often the easiest approach, so it's common.